# vscode The character U+0647 "ه" could be confused with the character U+006f "o", which is more

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode after update (November 2021 (version 1.63)) [Unicode highlighting#](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_unicode-highlighting)

vscode highlight same persian words, I want add persian characters to allowed characters. but how?

Thank you if you can help me

"The character U+0647 "ه" could be confused with the character U+006f "o", which is more common in source code."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the `Editor > Unicode Highlight: Allowed Characters` setting if you click on

`Add Item` you can paste or type your character in - but it appears you have to do it one by one which is sub-optimal.  I tried inputting some unicode **ranges** but nothing worked.

I tested it for your `ه` character and it works.  Once you paste it in, the value field will populate with `true` which is what you want.

The `Ambiguous Characters` setting shouldn't flag characters "common in the current user locale."  Is `ه` such a character?

---

I don't see a Persian Language Pack in the Marketplace so perhaps there is no way to change your vscode language to Persian.

More on locales here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Comment: this working for me. thanks

Comment: File > Settings > "Search for unicode"

Answer (score 13):

You can also uncheck `Settings > Editor > Unicode Highlight: Ambiguous Characters`

It's so much easier than adding characters every single time.

Comment: +1. The "Ambiguous Characters" feature is fundamentally broken, for example it marks all cyrillic `с`, `о`, `Н` and many other characters as "ambiguous".