# VScode jupyter notebook shows rectangles around some letters

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Currently working on VScode in a Jupyter Notebook and random cells have their letters in rectangles and can't figure out why.

[image]

When I copy some of the content of the second cell, the rectangles keep showing in the new pasted cell

Comment: Is it a text-specific issue or appears randomly? Have you reloaded your VSC to make sure the issue is persistent? Could you please explain more deeply the conditions under which the phenomenon occurs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix issue With VS Code: yellow orange border box around characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336593/fix-issue-with-vs-code-yellow-orange-border-box-around-characters)

Comment: thanks @rioV8, it got fixed by unchecking Editor › Unicode Highlight: Ambiguous Characters in the settings

Answer (score 0):

fixed, in settings, uncheck unicode highlight

[image]